# What is the reason for installing the SQL Analysing service for TFS?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, installation

I migrated to SQL 2017 and TFS 2018.

I am not using Reporting and Analyzing.

Everything worked out fine in the migration and we are running the new TFS server now for 2 weeks.

Now I found out that my SQL Server wasn't installed with the Analyzing Services. Seems that my Admin forgot it. Now I wonder that everything works even without this feature. And I know that I can still install it.

What is the requirement for SQL Analyzing Services for TFS-2018? Or is this only required when I use the TFS Reporting and Analyzing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQL Analyzing Services is required for TFS reporting only. You may work without it. But if you want to use TFS reports - you have to install MS SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About reporting: It is a separate installation package for the SQL Server and we dont't miss ist currently so it is also not installed.